# Python3 - lossless compression of long nested lists

Tags: algorithm, list, python-3.x, compression

I'm writing a compression algorithm to reduce the size of a combinatorial output that is a permutation of many input states. Modifying the format is not an option.

The goal is to preserve information about combinations of inputs that produce a certain output, so individual input states can be tokenized if they don't affect the output, conditional on all the other input states.

I have two list of lists,

```
inputs = [                       |   outputs = [
             [1,0,0.5,"foo"],    |                 [-0.25,"cold"],    
             [0,1,-0.5,"poo"],   |                 [0.66,"hot"],
                   .             |                       .
                   .             |                       .
                   .             |                       .
         ]                       |             ]
```

Properties:

- Input and output lists are the same length, and very long so memory is a concern
- Already paired by index
- Sub-lists are short and internally consistent in length and type within the input and output lists
- Sub-lists are composed of heterogenous types but I can cast them all to string if needed

I will pass them into a hash function like so:

```
list(map(lambda results: hashfunction(results[0],results[1]), list(zip(inputs,outputs))))
```

As far as I know, this is a memory efficient way to iterate them but before I do that, I want to reduce their length as much as I can.

Since the sub-lists are internally consistent, and I know some indexes are boolean, for equal output sub-lists I can reduce the input sub-lists like this without loss of information:

```
inputs = [... ,[1,0,0.5,1],[0,0,0.5,1], ...]
outputs = [... ,[0.3,"warm"],[0.3,"warm"], ...]
```

Is tokenized in-situ as:

```
inputs = [... ,["don't care",0,0.5,1], ...]
outputs = [... ,[0.3,"warm"], ...]
```

And the length of both inputs and outputs are reduced by 1.

Furthermore, I want to compress higher radix input columns, for example if I know that index 2 in any input sublist takes only the values [-0.5,0,0.5], if I find this pattern:

```
inputs = [... ,["don't care",0,-0.5,1],["don't care",0,0,1],["don't care",0,0.5,1], ...]
outputs = [... ,[0.1,"cake"],[0.1,"cake"],[0.1,"cake"], ...]
```

I want to reduce them similarly:

```
inputs = [... ,["don't care",0,"don't care",1], ...]
outputs = [... ,[0.1,"cake"], ...]
```

Unfortunately the patterns may not be adjacent, so I'm resorting to massive amounts of sorting and re-sorting to find reducible patterns and not only am I unable to compress the result set enough, the runtime/memory is untenable.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sory but I don't understand what you are trying to do at all, the title of the question says _Lossless compression_ but if you replace numbers with `"don't care"` isn't that losing information?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited the post to clarify a bit. I want to be lossless on the combinatorial information of the input vector and the output vector it produced, so reducing individual states within the input vector is fine as long as that information had no effect on the output vector.

Answer (score 0):

I look at this and think, "map-reduce".

Specifically you want to map each index to a key which is the output, and a value which is the input.  For each possible output you want to look at all possible input values and perform a series of operations on it to compress the expression for the input.  However you can perform this operation on one output at a time.

If memory was not a problem, you'd simply store key/values pair in a dictionary whose key is the output.  And iterate through the dictionary.

If memory is a challenge, you can write data to a file in the format `output, input`, use an external `sort` utility to sort it, then process it.  (Be warned, Unix sort needs a little cajoling to do an asciibetical sort, and you really need it to have done so.)  When you process that file you should have an iterator that reads one line at a time, and yields one output with all inputs that got there.  That iterator will be processed by a function that mangles that data and outputs your compressed input/output rules.